# Does shell affects the randomization produced by a seed

Tags: shell, random, system-verilog, uvm

I am an avid csh/tcsh user.
But the current environment I have to work on has all ksh scripts. The team works on k-shell.
So, if I select a seed and run a test in k-shell and c-shell, would the outcome be the same?
Seed is just one example, I want to know whether using alternate shell would create any divergence of end result?

Comment: Random sequence generated by *what*?

Comment: Assume you have a test case you want to run. It will randomize some sequence and drive. If I use a fixed seed (say SEED=123) and run on k-shell and c-shell, would the randomization remain the same?

Comment: What is doing the randomization? Where are the random numbers coming from? What are you setting the seed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a seeding mechanism for random number generators is to be able to reproduce results regardless of other factors. This means that as long as you're running the same compiled code for the simulator (same version, basically) you're going to get the same results when passing in a seed, regardless of what machine you're running on, what shell you use, etc.

Also, the shell you use has no end effect on the executable being started, other than setting environment variables that the program might use. You're going to have to make sure that you don't diverge in this point.

Comment: I see no discord as of now while using different shells. With a particular seed, I'm able to reproduce the same output.